# If $A$ is positive semi definite then $|u'Av|\leq (u'Au)^\frac 1 2 (v'Av)^\frac 1 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If $A$ is positive semi definite then prove that $$|u'Av|\leq (u'Au)^\frac 1 2 (v'Av)^\frac 1 2.$$

### Work done:

$$|u'A^\frac 1 2 A^\frac 1 2 v|=\left|\langle A^\frac 1 2 u, A^\frac 1 2 v\rangle \right|\leq ||A^\frac 1 2 u|| \,||A^\frac 12 v|| =(u'A^\frac 1 2 u)( v'A^\frac 1 2 v)$$

Comment: You are done, $\|A^{1/2]u\| = (u^T A u)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @user58955 could you provide the proof..because I think the same but I couldnot justify

Comment: $\|Mx\| = \langle Mx, Mx\rangle^{1/2} = (x^T M^2x)^{1/2}$, if M is symmetric